# ¿Cómo o porqué no puedo aplicar una función a un Array o un ArrayList en java?

Tags: java, funciones, bucle-for, arraylist, filereader

Me explico:

Estaba tratando el tema de logs en java y encontré esta página:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parsing-apache-access-log-in-java/

En el cual describen un algoritmo para contabilizar cuántas peticiones 200 hay,
intenté trasladar esto a un ejemplo con un archivo .txt como prueba.
Supongamos que el siguiente código es para leer cada línea de un archivo que contiene las mismas líneas que hay en el link anteriormente citado (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parsing-apache-access-log-in-java/)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files

public class ReadFile {

 public static void findSuccessIpCount(String record) {

       final String regex = "^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) " + 
               "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(\\S+)" + 
               " (\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)?\\s*\" (\\d{3}) (\\S+)";
  
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(record);
  
        // Creating a Hashmap containing string as
        // the key and integer as the value.
        HashMap<String, Integer> countIP = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
  
            String IP = matcher.group(1);
            String Response = matcher.group(8);
            int response = Integer.parseInt(Response);
  
            // Inserting the IP addresses in the 
            // HashMap and maintaining the frequency 
            // for each HTTP 200 code.
            if (response == 200) {
                if (countIP.containsKey(IP)) {
                    countIP.put(IP, countIP.get(IP) + 1);
                }
                else {
                    countIP.put(IP, 1);
                }
            }
        }
  
        // Printing the hashmap
        for (Map.Entry entry : countIP.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
**ArrayList <String> lineas = new ArrayList<String> ();** // Lista donde se almacenarán la cadenas

    try {
      File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = myReader.nextLine();
        lineas.add(data)
      }
      myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

for(String linea : lineas) {
   findSuccesIpCount(linea);
}
}
```

Cuando intento aplicar la función 'findSuccessIpCount(linea)' de la siguiente forma no imprime nada.
¿A qué se debe esto?
Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: A mi me ha funcionado con el ejemplo del log.txt de Omar. Vigila los asteriscos que sobran, que el método esté dentro del main, la 's' que falta en la llamada al método, y en 'lineas.add(data)' te falta el punto y coma. Tiene pinta que el problema sea la sintaxis del archivo log.txt.

Answer (score 0):

En el código que estás mostrando,

```
**ArrayList <String> lineas = new ArrayList<String> ();** // Lista donde se almacenarán la cadenas
```

Quita **

```
ArrayList <String> lineas = new ArrayList<String> (); // Lista donde se almacenarán la cadenas
```

El ciclo for va dentro del main.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
      ArrayList <String> lineas = new ArrayList<String> ();
      
      try {
      File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\omar\\Downloads\\text.txt"); //Asegurate de pasar la ruta de tu archivo txt correctamente.
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);  
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = myReader.nextLine();
        lineas.add(data);
      }
      myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }     
        
        for(String linea : lineas) {
           findSuccessIpCount(linea);  //El nombre es findSuccessIpCount no findSuccesIpCount
        }
  }
```

Tú archivo log debe de tener la siguiente sintaxis.

```
192.168.1.2 - - [17/Sep/2013:22:18:19 -0700] "GET /abc HTTP/1.1" 404 201
192.168.1.2 - - [17/Sep/2013:22:18:19 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
192.168.1.2 - - [17/Sep/2013:22:18:27 -0700] "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5325
192.168.1.2 - - [17/Sep/2013:22:18:27 -0700] "GET /wp/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=3.5.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 35292
192.168.1.3 - - [17/Sep/2013:22:18:27 -0700] "GET /wp/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/navigation.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 863
```

Comment: Los ** de arriba eran de la edición de la pregunta, ahí está todo bien, y abajo el ciclo for sí está dentro del main sólo que de nuevo por la edición tal vez no se vea dentro de él o me haya faltado un ' { ' . Intentaré corregir la sintaxis del archivo log